# node.js Use a variable inside the res.writeHeads() function

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, object, hyperlink

Heyo out there. I have the following problem:

I use this

```
res.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Length": template["stylecss"].length,
    "Connection": "Close",
    "X-XSS-Protection": "1; mode=block",
    "Server": servername,
    "Content-Type": "text/css"
});
```

to write the response headers to a client.

But now, i want to change the above code to serve predefined headers. Something like this:

var defresheads = { "X-Frame-Options": "deny", "X-Powered-By": servername };

```
res.writeHead(200, {
    defresheads,
    "Content-Length": template["stylecss"].length,
    "Connection": "Close",
    "X-XSS-Protection": "1; mode=block",
    "Server": servername,
    "Content-Type": "text/css"
});
```

Now, when i run the script, it says the following:

```
/home/dontrm/dontrm.js:47
            defresheads,
                       ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
```

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a helper function to concat your header objects, like

```
function jsonConcat(o1, o2) {
    for (var key in o2) {
        o1[key] = o2[key];
    }
    return o1;
}
```

And then you can use this as follows:

```
var defresheads = { "X-Frame-Options": "deny", "X-Powered-By": servername };
res.writeHead(200, jsonConcat(defresheads, {
    "Content-Length": template["stylecss"].length,
    "Connection": "Close",
    "X-XSS-Protection": "1; mode=block",
    "Server": servername,
    "Content-Type": "text/css"
}));
```